# pig conditional counting without using joins

Tags: apache-pig

Lets say I have data as below

```
Hour  status
12     pass
12     fail
13     fail
13     fail
13     pass
```

I need to calculate result as below

```
Hour passcount  failcount TotalCount
12    1           1          2
13    1           2          3
```

I know i can achieve this by splitting the records using 2 separate filters , one for 'pass' and one for 'fail' , counting them separately and join them back ( like below )

```
pass_data = FILTER data by (status matches 'pass') ;
pass_group = group pass_data by hour; 
pass_count = foreach pass_group  generate flatten(group), count($1) as pass_count ; 

original_count = foreach (group data by hour ) generate flatten(group),count($1) as total_count ; 
joined = join original_count by hour , pass_count by hour ;
```

But I **dont** like the above solution. Mainly because its lot of lines of code and actually there are multiple statuses other than 'pass' and 'fail'.
What i am looking for is something like below :

```
 awesome_count= foreach (group data by hour ) generate flatten(group),count($1) as total_count , count($1.status=='pass'?0:1) as pass_count ;
```

above doesnt work mainly because status is a bag for me ... but i tested this for some simple fields and pig doesnt like it.. throws all sort of errors. 
I hope is there is a better way or syntax i can leverage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your input , You can try nested foreach statement, The below logic will help you .

```
 records = LOAD '/home/user/localinputfiles/pass_fail.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (hour:int,result:chararray);

 records_grp = GROUP records BY hour;

 records_each = FOREACH records_grp 
                   {
                      passed_bag = FILTER records BY result == 'Pass';
                      failed_bag = FILTER records BY result == 'Fail' ;

                    GENERATE group, COUNT(passed_bag) as pass_cnt, COUNT(failed_bag) as fail_cnt ,COUNT(records) as total_cnt;
                   };

 dump records_each;
```